# WooCommerce extra fee on shipping cost if checkbox ship to other address is enabled

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkbox

Is there an option that, say if a customer wants to ship to another address other than his billing address, can there be an extra fee based on that checkbox? I want that if a customer unchecks that checkbox, a extra fee of € 12.50 is added on the shipping cost. If anyone knows, please let me know :)

The checkbox is the default woocommerce checkbox btw.

[image: WooCommerce default shipping checkbox]

Answer (score 0):

I already fixed it by adding below code to the functions.php within your own theme:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field' , 'remove_order_comments_optional_fields_label', 10, 4 );
function remove_order_comments_optional_fields_label( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
    // Only on checkout page for Order notes field
    if( 'ship_to_different_address' === $key && is_checkout() ) {
        $optional = '&nbsp;<span class="optional">(' . esc_html__( 'optional', 'woocommerce' ) . ')</span>';
        $field = str_replace( $optional, '', $field );
    }
    return $field;
}

// Ajax / jQuery script
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ship_to_different_address_script' );
function ship_to_different_address_script() {
    // On checkoutpage
    if( ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) ) :
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery( function($){
                if (typeof woocommerce_params === 'undefined')
                    return false;

                console.log('defined');

                $('input[name=ship_to_different_address]').click( function(){
                    var fee = $(this).prop('checked') === true ? '1' : '';

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: woocommerce_params.ajax_url,
                        data: {
                            'action': 'ship_to_different_address',
                            'ship_to_different_address': fee,
                        },
                        success: function (result) {
                            $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
                            console.log(result);
                        },
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}

// Get the ajax request and set value to WC session
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ship_to_different_address', 'get_ajax_ship_to_different_address' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ship_to_different_address', 'get_ajax_ship_to_different_address' );
function get_ajax_ship_to_different_address() {
    if ( isset($_POST['ship_to_different_address']) ) {
        WC()->session->set('ship_to_different_address', ($_POST['ship_to_different_address'] ? '1' : '0') );
        echo WC()->session->get('ship_to_different_address');
    }
    die();
}

// Add / Remove a custom fee
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_remove_ship_to_different_address', 10, 1 );
function add_remove_ship_to_different_address( $cart )
{
    // Only on checkout
    if ((is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) || is_cart())
        return;

    $fee_amount = 12.50;

    if (WC()->session->get('ship_to_different_address'))
        $cart->add_fee(__('Shipping fee', 'woocommerce'), $fee_amount);
}
```